# Magento add stock qty in backend new order creation

Tags: orders, stock, grid-serlization, grid

I was wondering how we could add a stock value in the 'backend new order creation' ... see image below

What we see now is that we enter an order, but in the next step are warned that ther is no stock ... so why not add the stock value as a column. Also we would very much like to filter on configurable products.

I was looking at app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create/Search/Grid.php

and wanted to add this code

```
if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
    $this->addColumn('qty',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Qty'),
            'width' => '30px',
            'type'  => 'number',
            'index' => 'qty',
    ));
}
```

and the field itself in collection

```
 protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes();
        /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $collection
            ->setStore($this->getStore())
            ->addAttributeToSelect($attributes)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array_keys(
                Mage::getConfig()->getNode('adminhtml/sales/order/create/available_product_types')->asArray()
            ))
            ->addAttributeToSelect('gift_message_available');

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addSaleableFilterToCollection($collection);

        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
            $collection->joinField('qty',
                'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left');
        }
```

but now the problems is that the 'order quantity' (most right column in image) is also called qty ... and now they are conflicting. **Question: How would I get the stock qty as 'alternate name' and show it?**

And could we also easily add configurable/simple product selector?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can simply set a different alias for the inventory quantity. Something like `inv_qty` see edits below.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes();
    /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection
        ->setStore($this->getStore())
        ->addAttributeToSelect($attributes)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array_keys(
                Mage::getConfig()->getNode('adminhtml/sales/order/create/available_product_types')->asArray()
            ))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('gift_message_available');

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addSaleableFilterToCollection($collection);

    if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
        $collection->joinField('inv_qty',
            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
            'qty',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
            'left');
    }
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

And then add this new column using the alias as the index and setting a new id for it.

```
if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
    $this->addColumn('inv_qty',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Qty'),
            'width' => '30px',
            'type'  => 'number',
            'index' => 'inv_qty',
        ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add onto the above answer by David,

remember that you may have to

```
return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
```

instead of

```
return parent::_prepareCollection();
```